# How to connect and synchronize Lotus Notes calendar with Windoes CE custom application

Tags: .net, calendar, windows-ce, lotus-notes

We are developing custom appication on Win CE and we need to synchronize data on device with calendar of selected user.

thanks for help

Comment: You might want to ask a more specific question, and share some code as well.

Comment: Pleaes specify the setup of your system: ActiveSync/LAN/WiFi etc. What do you have so far? Do you know how to pull data from Lotus calendar?

Comment: We have LAN connection. we need to get get just main data from meetign room calendars. I don't know how to pull data from Lotus Calendar. see some screen shots http://www.behance.net/Gallery/Agenda-Display-GUI/530974

Answer (score 0):

There are third party applications that will do that for you.
We used CommonTime's Cadenza in the past, but that was years ago.